# TextView inside TableLayout and TableRow doesn't wrap text

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, android-tablelayout

I have a small problem with a fragment in my application that shows out details about a Google Place. The problem is in displaying the reviews of other users.

As shown in this image the text in the comments textview is not fully displayed. Is there a way to make the textview go to a new line?

Image of the problem:
http://postimg.org/image/84frbxd23/

I'm adding the TableRow and TextView dynamically from code. I've tried the following things:

1. setting ellipsize to end
2. setting scrollable to true
3. setting maxLines to 10

Here's my layout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/reviews"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/openhours"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</TableLayout>
```

And here is the code that adds the rows and textviews:

```
        //Dinamically create table
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.reviews);
        TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(rootView.getContext());
        tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        tr_head.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView label_author = new TextView(rootView.getContext());
        label_author.setText("Author");
        label_author.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_author.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(label_author);// add the column to the table row here

        TextView label_comment = new TextView(rootView.getContext());
        label_comment.setText("Comment"); // set the text for the header
        label_comment.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_comment.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(label_comment); // add the column to the table row here


        table.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //if it has reviews display them
        if(currentP.hasReviews()) {
            for (Review r : currentP.getReviews()) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(rootView.getContext());
                tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //Create two columns to add as table data
                // Create a TextView to add date
                TextView author = new TextView(rootView.getContext());
                author.setText(r.getAuthor());
                author.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                author.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                author.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                tr.addView(author);

                TextView comment = new TextView(rootView.getContext());
                comment.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
                comment.setText(r.getReview());
                comment.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                comment.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                comment.setMaxLines(10);
                comment.setId(r.getId());
                tr.addView(comment);


                // finally add this to the table row
                table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the width of author TextView constant so that it doesnt expand too much and shrink the Comment TextView. For the Comment TextView set the given layout params so that it can expand vertically and doesn't get cutoff.

```
                // Create a TextView to add date
                TextView author = new TextView(this);
                author.setText(authorName);
                author.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                author.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                author.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                author.setWidth(150); // good idea to set width for author name so that its fixed
                tr.addView(author);

                TextView comment = new TextView(this);
                comment.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
                comment.setText(bigComment);
                comment.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                comment.setMaxLines(10);

               // Provide this parameter so that the whole text can be seen with no cutoff
                comment.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
                    tr.addView(comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the LayoutParams to the `label_comment`. Set `WRAP_CONTENT` as the width.

Also, I recommend you use `MATCH_PARENT` instead of `FILL_PARENT` since, the last one is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a `layout_width` parameter to your comments and set them to `wrap_content`.